# how to create a wpf datagrid without binding to anything?

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

I want to create a datagrid without binding to anything. User can add/delete/edit data and the code will collect the data programatically. I did the following but the grid does not allow me to add new row.

```
<DataGrid Name="dgData" CanUserAddRows="True" MinHeight="100">
            <DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Column1"></DataGridTextColumn>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Column2"></DataGridTextColumn>
            </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

When I run the application, the grid is shown with only headers. Unlike winform DataGridView that gives an empty first row. There is no way I can add a new row on the GUI.

Comment: Why do you want to do this? Going WPF without bindings is like going back to dinosaur winforms. What do you want that for? do you really hate yourself so much?

Comment: I am using wpf because the entire application is wpf. But for this specific grid, I want to do some manual stuff.

Comment: See my answer, Ryan. Please be more specific about "does not allow me to add new row".

Comment: @Ryan I seriously recommend you learn MVVM. Otherwise you'll suffer A LOT. WPF is not like other (dinosaur) UI frameworks where you code stuff manually. You need to create a proper ViewModel and the proper bindings in XAML to do stuff. Otherwise your code is going to be crappy and people are going to hate you, I mean your coworkers.

Comment: Classic [X Y Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Comment: Why not bind to an empty collection?

Comment: @cheedep So I must binding to a dummy collection? No natural way to do this?

Comment: @Ryan Why is it a "dummy" collection?? What are you placing inside this DataGrid? Why not just do it the right way, which is easier btw?

Comment: @HighCore My case is complicated. A single row on the grid is not mapping to a meaningful object. I will create some business object based on the grid data when user click some "run" button.

Comment: @Ryan Regardless of that, If there's ANY logic behind what you're doing, then there IS a way to create a proper ViewModel to do it right, and not having to resort to winforms-style hacks of reading the UI elements' properties in procedural code.

Comment: @Ryan why don't you post a screenshot of what you need? so we can tell you how to do it in WPF.

Comment: @HighCore. Thanks. It is very simple. In winform DataGridView, when you set AllowUserAddNewRow property true, the grid without any data will show an empty first row. Everytime you enter data in the new row, it appends a new row. I just want this behavior in WPF DataGrid when I do not bind the grid to any collection.

Comment: @Ryan I don't understand... What do you want a DataGrid for if it doesn't represent (some kind of) Data Items?? My brain is unable to get it. BTW if you expect winforms behavior you should go back to winforms. WPF is a much better framework and removes the need for the horrible amount of hacks needed to do anything useful in winforms.

Comment: Guys just tell him it's not possible if it's not possible instead of being rude. He is not interested in being flamed for no apparent reason :)

Answer (score 4):

You still need to set (or bind) the `ItemsSource` to an empty collection that supports adding (implements `IList`), also you should bind the columns to properties of the item datatype (or let the `DataGrid` create them for you), otherwise they won't show anything.

Answer (score 2):

I know my answer is pretty late, but someone might still come here and benift from it. So basically I did not find a way to fill the DataGrid without Binding in WPF but I found a way to make binding with an anonymous type with dynamically named object properties.

```
List<object> myList = new List<object>();
dynamic obj = new ExpandoObject();
((IDictionary<String, Object>)obj)["PropertyName"] = "PropertyValue";
myList.Add(obj);
MyDataGrid.ItemsSource = myList;
```